# Why AWS EMR step is not failed when exception from Scala Spark app thrown

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have nect code in main method:

```
 try {
      tappSparkEngine.process();
    }catch{
      case e: Exception => LOG.error(e.toString)
              throw e
    }
```

There is a condition when exception is thrown and this is recorded at logs:

> 2018-04-02 03:05:04 ERROR TappSparkApp$:55 - java.lang.Exception:
>   Midnight points are missed when expected

And this is last record at logs. 
But EMR job step is not failed state, but completed. Why so? And how make it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Return a non-zero value from your program.

   Eg: in Java

   system.exit(-1)

   In below link, the programmer is doing the same thing in python
   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/submitting-user-applications-with-spark-submit/
2. Try wrapping the exception in org.apache.spark.SparkException